# What is $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/((x-1)^3)$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

What is $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/((x-1)^3)$ isomorphic? ($\mathbb{Z}_5=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.)

Since $(x-1)^3$ is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, it is not a prime ideal and the quotient ring is not a field. Thus $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/((x-1)^3)\ncong\mathbb{Z}_5$.

In this case, $(x-1)+(x-1)^2\neq(1)$ so I can't apply Chinese Remainder theorem here.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/((x-1)^3)
=
\mathbb{Z}_5[x-1]/((x-1)^3)
\cong
\mathbb{Z}_5[t]/(t^3)
\cong
\mathbb{Z}_5[u], \ u^3=0
$$

Comment: and so it's like a higher-order [dual number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) over $\mathbb F_5$.

Comment: Why  not  $\mathbb{Z}_5[t]/(t^3) \cong \{a+bt+ct^2,\ a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \} = \mathbb{Z}_{5^3}$ ? what is going wrong here ?

Comment: I didn't get. Which multiplication formula ?

Comment: Multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_5[t]/(t^3)$ is not the same as in $ \mathbb{Z}_{5^3}$. Try it.

Comment: Alright.Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for the answer, lhf